# Did Naamah practice "ritual murder and cannibalism" with Ham?

Tags: genesis

In Genesis 4:22 it is written,

> "Tubal -Cain's sister was Naamah"

I am trying to establish if the Quote below (found on the internet) has any truth to it, and also who was Naamah mentioned in Genesis 4:22? who was her husband? and what became of her after Genesis 4:22?

> Ham was persuaded by his consort Naamah, to practice ritual murder and cannibalism and
>   the word "cannibalism" comes from Canaan and the demon god Baal.
>   Eustace Mullins, The Curse of Canaan p. 12 (1987). By eating
>   fair-skinned persons, he was told, his descendants would regain their
>   superior qualities. Eustace Mullins, The Curse of Canaan p. 11 (1987).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears this author is making up everything in the quotes you've provided, at least as far as the text of the bible goes.

- No biblical text mentions Naamah beyond Genesis 4.
- Ham's wife is not named.
- No biblical text says Ham committed cannibalism.
- The word 'cannibal' is an English corruption of the Spanish name of a tribe of American natives, whom Spanish settlers claimed ate humans; connecting it to 'Canaan' and 'Baal' is historically untrue.

Comment: About the last point - the truth is that the idea that Canaan was black long preceded black slavery in America. It is already put forward in the Midrash Bereshit Rabba 36:7 as can be seen here in the Hebrew: http://www.daat.co.il/daat/tanach/raba1/36.htm

Comment: Also, the Midrash in Breshit Rabba 23:3 mentions an opinion that Naama was Noach's wife: http://www.daat.co.il/daat/tanach/raba1/23.htm

Comment: Also, the name Naamah means "pleasant" - not the kind of name I would associate with a cannibal.

Comment: @BruceJames,I feel that you have missed the 'point' of my question in which i stated "I am trying to establish if the Quote below (found on the internet) has any TRUTH to it." Please understand,I did not post the 'assumption' concerning Naamah;on the internet.Your down-vote and comment have left me feeling that the intention of my question was to 'ridicule' my Jewish brothers and sisters.This was not my intention.One could ask this question," Was Paul crucified up-side down?" (as some people believe) to find if there is a truth that Paul was crucified in this way.

Comment: @bagpipes -- I was just giving you another reason to believe that there is no basis for the quoted material to raise its conclusions.

Comment: @BruceJames , O.K. and thanks for your reply.I did try to delete the question; but the system will not allow me to do so.

Comment: How can it be proven that the word cannibal is just a coruption of some other word if Cana Baal means the god of Cannaan who was accused of cannibalism by Jeremiah ?
lets not forget that he tried to warn them that if they worshiped the baals of cannaan
then jerusalem would be destroyed and they would be taken into captivity and guess what ? thats what really did happen !!!

Comment: @roderick I cannot find any references to *Cana Baal* in Jeremiah. Further, *Canaan* is not mentioned by name in Jeremiah. A Google search for *Cana Baal* only leads to a book that says 'cannibalism' comes from *Cana Baal*, but the author provides no sources for this claim, and the book honestly looks like nonsense. The word 'cannibal' came to English through a Spanish term for some natives encountered by European explorers. It has no relation to *Cana* or *Baal*.

Comment: @Jewels I caution you about making a statement that Canaan was black, his ancestors are not black. [This](http://www.pseudepigrapha.com/jubilees/10.htm) explains the sin of Canaan(From the Book of Jubilees-Ch.10:27-34)

Comment: @Tau I made no such statement of my own opinion, I merely quoted ancient sources that make the statement, which are relevant considering that MarkEdward claims that there is no historical basis connecting an African tribe with the name Canaan.